# Test method inside of C++ classes

Tags: c++, testing

Not the best question title, so I think an example is the best way to describe it.

I created a little program in Java to practice coding up a LinkedList, and then using that LinkedList in a Stack or Queue. [Here's the entire program](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/59683/linkedlist-to-be-used-in-a-stack-or-queue) if you're interested.

The question is about the main() class in the Java classes. In each of them I have just some basic, non-interactive test operations. Just to make sure everything is in working order.

Is there a C++ way of...replicating this functionality, hopefully separate from the main.cpp file that actually handles all of the user interface/interactive stuff.

In other words, say I had:
main.cpp  --  The entry point into the program that handles all the user interaction
LinkedList.h  -- Header file
LinkedList.cpp -- Implementation file, is there a way to add some basic testing functionality that would only be ran if LinkedList.cpp was complied and ran on it's own, independent of main.cpp

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do what you want is to unit test the linked list. There are many good frameworks, I suggest you take a look at GoogleTest/Mock. Another unit testing framework is Cppunit. Of course, such fw:s can also be used for testing groups of classes, i.e. not just unit testing but testing of subsystems.

https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/
https://code.google.com/p/googletest/

http://cppunit.sourceforge.net/doc/cvs/cppunit_cookbook.html